# how do I configure stunnel to serve https

Tags: webserver

I'm wondering if anyone has configured https using [stunnel](ftp://ftp.stunnel.org/stunnel/) without using apache or any web server. I will be using this to replace our hudson build system which currently is running via apache https (winstone is proxyed via apache) which is kind of heavy.

I was the one who configured the apache https in our hudson build system but I can't seem to understand as to how to do it the stunnel way.

Here's a sample run of stunnel in my CLI:

```
buggedtech~$ stunnel
Reading configuration from file /usr/local/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
Snagged 64 random bytes from /Users/icasimpan/.rnd
Wrote 1024 new random bytes to /Users/icasimpan/.rnd
PRNG seeded successfully
Using DH parameters from /usr/local/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
DH initialized with 512 bit key
ECDH initialized
Certificate: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
Certificate loaded
Key file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
Private key loaded
SSL context initialized for service https
Configuration successful
Clients allowed=125
FD=8 in non-blocking mode
FD=9 in non-blocking mode
FD=10 in non-blocking mode
Option SO_REUSEADDR set on accept socket
Error binding https to ::1:443
bind: Permission denied (13)
```

Thanks in advance,

Ismael Casimpan :)

Comment: It seems like you've started `stunnel` as a normal user, which then tries to bind to port 443. Generally, ports below 1024 can only be used by root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip wag. I also realized that so I tried doing sudo and it now works! :)